# How to call on a yaml node in java

Tags: java, yaml, minecraft, bukkit

```
    simpleco:
      expenses: 100
      revenue: 150
```

How do I call on the node "simpleco"?  I am making a bukkit plugin and i need to be able to call on this.  The file format is yml/Yaml.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Bukkit has the method [`getKeys(false)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getKeys(boolean)), that you can call on a [`ConfigurationSection`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html) to get all nodes inside it. The usage of this api is simple:

```java
public class MyPlugin extends JavaPlugin {
    public void onEnable(){ 
        Set<String> keys = this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("simpleco").getKeys(false);
    }
}
```

The set called `keys` will now contain `expenses` and `revenue`.

You can then do a for loop over it so you can read all the things:

```java
ConfigurationSection sec = this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("simpleco")
Set<String> keys = sec.getKeys(false);
for(String key : keys) {
    int value = sec.getInt(key);
    System.out.println(key + "=" + value);
}
```